# Determine the kind of algebraic structure of a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-groups

We have been given a set $A=\{f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}|f \text{ is bounded}\}$. For all $f,g \in A$ has been defined point by point operation: $(f\ast g)(x)=|f(x)+g(x)|$. We have to determine the algebraic structure.

My question is, that when trying to prove it isn't associative (I might be wrong here), can I choose $f(x)=1, g(x)=-1, h(x)=0$ or does the addition condition ($f$ is bounded) not allow that?

Comment: Why would the condition ($f$ is bounded) disallow the bounded constant functions to $-1,0,1$?

Comment: I'm not sure at what point the fact that f is bounded comes into play so thought maybe I can't choose random values for $f(x)$.

Comment: I don't understand how ||f(x)+g(x)|+h(x)| and |f(x)+|g(x)+h(x)|| can be equal :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'algebra' is clearly commutative and unital with unit the constant zero function, but it's not associative. It's not associative precisely by your example: $$||f(x)+g(x)|+h(x)|=|0+0|=0$$But: $$|f(x)+|g(x)+h(x)||=|1+|-1||=2\neq0$$

You are allowed to pick any bounded functions $(0,1)\to\Bbb R$ whatsoever... as $1$, $-1$ and $0$ are all finite, the constant maps thereto are bounded. I think you're overthinking this.

Comment: Thanks, it was in our test and I didn't believe it was that simple.